# MySQL update from nested SELECT query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables which are getting different values from different sources.
One table called `stock` has 2 fields, code and stock, while other have code, stock (and bunch more not relevant to what I want to do)
Basically my current query for checking if there are enough quantities is following

```
SELECT * 
FROM products
WHERE products.code 
NOT IN (SELECT stock.code from stock) 
AND products.stock > 0 
AND products.product_active = 1
```

Which works, but I would like to extend it to UPDATE `stock` field of the table `products` to value 0 for the results of the above query.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE products p
LEFT JOIN stock s ON p.code = s.code
SET p.stock = 0
WHERE p.stock > 0 AND p.product_active = 1 AND s.code IS NULL
```

Comment: Cheers, works perfectly!I have tried to do it myself at first but failed miserably...

Answer (score 2):

So why don't you do it? Its very similar to what you just did :

```
UPDATE products p
SET p.stock = 0
WHERE p.code NOT IN(SELECT s.code FROM stock s)
  AND p.stock > 0
  AND p.product_Active = 1
```

I don't like to use `IN()` statement, since it doesn't handle `NULL` values very well, you can also use `NOT EXISTS()` instead of it:

```
UPDATE products p
SET p.stock = 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM stock s 
                 WHERE p.code = s.code)
  AND p.stock > 0
  AND p.product_Active = 1
```

Comment: For the record this works as well, however someone already upvoted and I have tested @Giorgos solution first and mark it as solution...

Comment: yes you were, but someone already upvoted his solution, thus is showed me his suggestion as first - thus I have tired his first... and then tried yours as well, which as said works too, thus I have upvoted it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, as you might notice when reading question, I am not really experienced with (My)SQL queries, but for some reason though that his solution gave me both solution and optimization(?) in terms of using JOIN instead of SUB QUERY. I really cannot judge which one is better tho. :( I can try it out on local base and see what will be faster and then change solution accordingly since other than that I have no idea what might be better approach. Other than that I can only thank you for participating since you gave another aproach as well @sagi